# Pandas Float64 nans are not recognized

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas does not recognize NaNs which were computed as a result of an arithmetic operation between non-NaN `Float64` and NaN `float64`.
Example below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print(f'{pd.__version__=}')
# pd.__version__='1.5.1'
print(f'{np.__version__=}')
# np.__version__='1.23.4'


df = pd.DataFrame({'NonNaN-Float64': [1], 'NaN-float64': [np.NaN], 'NaN-Float64': [np.NaN]})
df = df.astype({'NonNaN-Float64': 'Float64', 'NaN-float64': 'float64', 'NaN-Float64': 'Float64'})
df['res'] = df['NonNaN-Float64'] * df['NaN-float64']


print(df)
#    NonNaN-Float64  NaN-float64  NaN-Float64  res
# 0             1.0          NaN         <NA>  NaN

print(df.dtypes)
# NonNaN-Float64    Float64
# NaN-float64       float64
# NaN-Float64       Float64
# res               Float64
# dtype: object

print(df.isna())
#    NonNaN-Float64  NaN-float64  NaN-Float64    res
# 0           False         True         True  False
```

The last element of the last output expected to be `True` as `res` is actually NaN.

Why is this a case and how can it be fixed (except for obvious "astyping" everything to a single dtype)?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me, if the dtypes are all "float64" and not the title case "Float64" in df.astype(...)